# using a delegate to handle events within an interface, C#

Tags: c#, events, interface, delegates

I am trying to study MTA98-731 as a C# beginner. I could not figure out the solution for the following question, can anyone help me? Thanks;

Imagine that you are writing code for creating and handling events in your program. The class SampleClass needs to implement the following interface:

```
public delegate void SampleDelegate();
public interface ISampleEvents
{
event SampleDelegate SampleEvent;
void Invoke();
}
```

You need to write code for the SampleClass and for a test method that creates an instance of the SampleClass and invokes the event. What code should you write?

I have written the following:

```
public class SampleClass:ISampleEvents
{
    public SampleClass()
    {
        SampleEvent = new SampleDelegate(Invoke);

    }

    //public event SampleDelegate SampleEvent ;

    public void Invoke()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Invoke");
    }


    public event SampleDelegate SampleEvent;
}


class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

                 SampleClass s = new SampleClass();


    }
}
```

but it does not seem to invoke the Invoke() function. Can someone help? I am clueless :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is code for raising event:

```
public class SampleClass : ISampleEvents
{
    public event SampleDelegate SampleEvent; // declare event

    public void Invoke()
    {
        if (SampleEvent != null) // check if handlers attached
           SampleEvent(); // raise event (i.e. invoke event delegate)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to check if there are existing subscribers to event before raising it. Usage of sample class:

```
class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SampleClass s = new SampleClass(); // create instance of class with event
        s.SampleEvent += SampleEventHandler; // subscribe to event
        s.Invoke(); // invoke some logic which raises event
    }

    private static void SampleEventHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoked"); // handle event
    }
}
```

When adding event handler you can use just method name

```
s.SampleEvent += SampleEventHandler;
```

Which is syntax sugar for creating new delegate:

```
s.SampleEvent += new SampleDelegate(SampleEventHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I misunderstood the question, I thought Invoke() was a method needs to pass to SampleEvent. On top of that, I really did not understand delegate and event.

Comment: @AlliceSmash welcome :) There is nice tutorials on msdn, which I recommend you to read [Delegates Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx) and [Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `s.Invoke()`

and then in the Invoke method you need to invoke the event:

```
var ev = SampleEvent;
if (ev != null) ev();
```